# Solving a navigation issue in WP7 when app returns to the foreground?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

Unfortunately I'm more than half way done with the app and I just realized an odd bug when navigating forward after the app returns to the foreground from tombstoning.

Basically the first time the app runs there are no issues with the navigation. When I exit the app and return to it, everything deserializes and is loaded into the page no issues. Then when I hit the back button and go to previous pages everything works like it should.

Now as soon as I navigate to a new page (not in the backstack) the screen goes black. If you hit the back button the app closes abdruptly. I put a break point in the constructor of the page I'm navigating to, to see if its working, and its not even being created. For some reason my navigation doesn't work anymore. Any ideas?

**NOTE:** I'm using the WP7 7.1 SDK and I'm also using Telerik Controls for WP7.

Comment: 1) Can you determine how much memory you are using at the time of the crash? 2) Is the crash occuring on an emulator or a device?

Comment: @RichardSzalay it's happening on both. I wanted to check but I have no idea how to. Strangely enough it simply just doesn't navigate to a new page. And you could leave it like that and nothing happens. But as soon as you hit back it closes. BTW no exception is thrown when it closes.

Comment: @loyalpenguin the times I've had crashes like that, they have all been StackOverflow (due to an accidental recursive property definition) ie private int value; public int Value { get { return value; } set { Value = value; } }

Comment: Can you get the Exception details , if possible by debugging application ??

Comment: @Santhu I tried but no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds consistant with a forced close. According to [this page](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2011/02/10/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Memory-Usage.aspx), navigating has a big impact on memory usage so it sounds like you're clocking over 90mb, which is grounds for automatic termination.

You can monitor memory using the [Gary McGlennon's debug memory counter](http://dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2010/09/27/Debug-Memory-Counter-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx).